# TypeError: Cannot read property '$oid' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a little problem with MongoDB. I am developing a CRUD application with MongoDB, React and Node and as you can see in my title I'm getting an error and the error occurs when trying to save an existing document, not when creating one.

The error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500`.

I am looping over my objects to see if there is is any particular key, and if there is I will give it a objectID. This is the code that's creating the error by the way:

```
let convert = obj => {
  for (key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue
    if (obj[key].$oid) {
      obj[key] = objectId(obj[key].$oid)
    }
  }
}
```

So my questions is; why does this error occur when updating an existing document, and how can I stop my application from crashing?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Could be because of the implicit global variable `key` you create. Try adding `let` in loop: `for (let key in obj) {`.

Comment: I hate passing endorsements, but it does seem like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here. https://github.com/mongodb-js/extended-json

Comment: @dfsq hey dude! Thanks for replying, but I still get the error :(